# How to push a docker image from a website to a remote device and run it automatically

Tags: docker, nginx

how can I push a nginx image from a website created in django to a remote device(any pc which is already configured) and make the image run automatically or how can I make a nginx container run in a remote device from a website.

Comment: Have you looked at Jenkins?
https://www.jenkins.io/

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

In order to run the nginx image as a container on a "remote device" it will need  [docker engine](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#docker-engine) installed on it. If you want to remotely trigger a deployment on any machine you can use Jenkins. So essentially on every remote device you will need docker & jenkins. You can create a jenkins job to start your nginx container based on any of the trigger mechanisms available on jenkins.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I want to run the image as a container from my website which I built using django, How can I automate that with a trigger from my website.